# Error deploying webapplication to wso2as-5.0.3

Tags: wso2-as

i have the following errors while deploying a maven web application on wso2 application server:

> java.lang.Exception: Error while deploying webapp:
>   *StandardContext[invent360.war].File[/home/iceman95/Development/wso2as-5.3.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/invent360.war]
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.handleWebappDeployment(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:405)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.handleWarWebappDeployment(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:212)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.handleHotDeployment(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:179)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.deploy(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:144)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.AbstractWebappDeployer.deployThisWebApp(AbstractWebappDeployer.java:224)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.AbstractWebappDeployer.deploy(AbstractWebappDeployer.java:114)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.webapp.deployer.WebappDeployer.deploy(WebappDeployer.java:42) at
>   org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
>   at
>   org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
>   at
>   org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
>   at
>   org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
>   at
>   org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
>   at
>   org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)
>   at
>   org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59)
>   at
>   org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:93)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:138)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.CarbonTomcatException: Webapp failed to deploy
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.addWebApp(CarbonTomcat.java:356) at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.addWebApp(CarbonTomcat.java:252) at
>   org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.handleWebappDeployment(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:314)
>   ... 23 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/invent360]]
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.addWebApp(CarbonTomcat.java:344) ... 25 more,*

can any one please help.

wso2 app server version is :5.3.0
The application has previously been successfully deployed to a jboss enterprise app server without this error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to deploy your webapp in Tomcat or TomEE? WSO2 Application Server 5.3.0 is not a fully fledged JEE container like JBoss. 5.3.0 supports only JEE web profile (through Apache TomEE)